# Will providing structured video data when only a video thumbnail is shown still show rich snippets on Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, video

My client wants to have a video thumbnail on their website that when clicked will open up a modal with the video embedded.

We want to put structured data on the video but, because the video is not seen by users on load, would this information be seen as less valuable and possibly prevent the rich snippets?

The reason the client does not want the video on the page is because this will push down the products and could affect their conversions.